# Javascript - How to delete selected picture?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, preview

This is the code, so here is code for multiple preview images. So I want to delete the selected image? So when you upload images you click on image and image disappeared but it's only hidden not deleted?

How I can fix this? Because I'm using `.remove();` method but nothings happened, its just hidden image

```
    $("#files").on("change", handleFileSelect);
    selDiv = $("#selectedFiles");
    $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);
    $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);
  });

  var selDiv = "";
  var storedFiles = [];
  function handleFileSelect(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
    var device = $(e.target).data("device");
    filesArr.forEach(function(f) {

      if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
        return;
      }
      storedFiles.push(f);

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var html = "<div><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" data-file='" + f.name + "' class='selFile' title='Click to remove'>" + f.name + "<br clear=\"left\"/></div>";
        $("#selectedFiles").append(html);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    });

  }

  function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0, len = storedFiles.length; i < len; i++) {
      data.append('files', storedFiles[i]);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'handler.cfm', true);

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);
        alert(e.currentTarget.responseText + ' items uploaded.');
      }
    }

    xhr.send(data);
  }

  function removeFile(e) {
    var file = $(this).data("file");
    for (var i = 0; i < storedFiles.length; i++) {
      if (storedFiles[i].name === file) {
        storedFiles.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();
  }
```

This is my simple HTML

```
<script src="aa.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
  <div id="selectedFiles"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `.remove()` seems to be working fine. I tested your code on jsfiddle with few changes and it deletes the entire time (not just hides it)

Comment: @Kalimah I edited my post, you have now screenshot. This is a screenshot after you click on the image, so picture its hidden, I still have a jpg file but supposed to be deleted?

Comment: You mean the image **name** still there instead of the default "no file chosen"?

Comment: @Kalimah Yes, it's still chosen

Comment: @Kalimah What to do?

Comment: I am sorry. I can not help any further unless I see a live example.

Answer (score -1):

You need to reset the input value:

```
 function removeFile(e) {
    var file = $(this).data("file");
    for (var i = 0; i < storedFiles.length; i++) {
      if (storedFiles[i].name === file) {
        storedFiles.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();

  // add it here
   jQuery("#files").val("");
  }
```

Comment: I edited post again. See the screenshot, when I select multiple images, and I want to delete one of them, I clicked, and the second picture it's still there but I have here No file chosen, as its full reset for all pictures

Comment: Because it's not working. Actually it's working but not that what I asked...

Comment: That's not a cause for a downvote. At least provide a live example that I can inspect.

Comment: How I can give you a live example? I gave you an all code, what I need to do next?

Comment: Either point to the site where the code is hosted, or use https://jsfiddle.net/ to show the example and provide the link here.

Comment: Just try with classic index.html and code for js, I need solution for this, so if you can help please.

Comment: What I can do now?